# Project permissions on odoo v11

Tags: python, project, acl, odoo

I'm trying to setup rights on Project for my Odoo v11 instance with the following requirements:

- A project manager can only manage his/her projects
- Project member can only rights to his/her assigned tasks.

I'm playing around the record rules and access controls list but helpless.
Is there any document about it that I can read?

Comment: You can check following official doc of odoo related to security. Like is: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/security.html

Comment: Thanks, Keval. I will look at it.